# using radiobutton.Checked in another class (issues with static/non-static stuff)

Tags: c#, winforms

Using the VS Designer, I created a Window (Form1) with few radiobuttons. From another class, I try to make a statement which executes if a radiobutton is checked.

```
    public static string printRailType()
    { 
        if (Form1.rb60E1.Checked)
        {
            return "60E1";
        }

        else if (Form1.rb49E1.Checked)
        {
            return "49E1";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Rail type not selected.";
        }
```

However, I am having issues with it, which appear as an error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'RailCalc.Form1.rb60E1'
>   Same for Form1.rb49E1.

So, to fix these errors, I create an instance of Form1:

```
    public static string printRailType()
    {
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1(); 
        if (frm1.rb60E1.Checked)
        {
            return "60E1";
        }

        else if (frm1.rb49E1.Checked)
        {
            return "49E1";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Rail type not selected.";
        }
    }
```

However, it still prints that railtype is not selected, even though a radio button is selected.

It seems that frm1 is an instance of class Form1, but it is created and reset (no radiobuttons selected).

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I'm not all too good with C#, but you have a `static` method and in there you are trying to access a `non-static` field or property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works another way and the keyword is event, in your case it is [CheckedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So you have to handle it and put the code in the handler:

```
    if (this.rb60E1.Checked)
    {
        return "60E1";
    }

    else if (this.rb49E1.Checked)
    {
        return "49E1";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Rail type not selected.";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I do not quite understand where to put this code.

Comment: as I written, the keyword is CheckedChanged event and even gave you the link, which contains the description and the sample. Show us what you have tried

Comment: Okay, it seems to be a really primitive thinking, but I got it working this way: I created a string variable called RailType in Form1 and used CheckedChanged events to set it a value, either 60E1 or 49E1, otherwise string is empty.

Then I made a public method called getRailType which return this string, and I use it in Calc class.

It is working, however I highly doubt it is a professional way to do so.

Answer (score -1):

It's because the new Form1 you made to fix the error is a completely new form, not the one where you click the radiobuttons. You have to give the class a reference to Form1 somewhere and somehow, possibly at the place where you are creating the class.